# How to call a method in a Vue component from programmatically inserted component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm trying to call a method from a child component which is programatically inserted.
Here is my code.

MultipleFileUploader.vue

```js
<template>

    <div class="form-group" id="multiple-file-uploader">
        <div>
            <multiple-file-uploader-part
                    :name="uploadername" :index="1"
                    @remove="deleteUploader" @fileselected="fileSelected($event)">
            </multiple-file-uploader-part>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import MultipleFileUploaderPart from './MultipleFileUploaderPart.vue';
    let index_count = 1;
    export default {
        components: {
            'multiple-file-uploader-part':MultipleFileUploaderPart,
        },
        props: {
            uploadername: {
                type: String,
                default: 'files',
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                next_id:1,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fileSelected: function (target) {
                var UploaderPart = Vue.extend(MultipleFileUploaderPart);
                new UploaderPart().$on('fileselected','fileSelected')
                    .$mount('#multiple-file-uploader');
            },
            deleteUploader: function (idToRemove) {
                this.uploaders = this.uploaders.filter(
                    uploaders_id => {
                        return uploaders_id.id !== idToRemove;
                    }
                )
            }
        },
    }
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

MultipleFileUploaderPart.vue

```js
<template>
    <div v-bind:id="name + '['+index+']'">
        <div class="input-group margin">
            {{index}}
            <input type="file" accept="application/pdf,image/jpeg,image/png"
                   v-bind:name="name + '['+index+']'"
                   v-on:change="fileSelectedMethod($event.target)">
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button @click="removeClicked"
                        class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                        v-if="index != 1"
                        type="button">
                    Delete{{index}}
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <p v-if="size_error" style="color: red">File size must be less than 2MB</p>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
            },
            index: {
                type: Number,
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                size: '',
                size_error: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            removeClicked: function () {
                document.getElementById(this.name+'[' + this.index + ']' ).remove();
                this.$emit('remove', this.index);
            },
            fileSelectedMethod: function (target) {
                this.size = target.files[0].size;
                if (this.size < 2000000) {
                    this.size_error = false;
                    this.$emit('fileselected', target);
                } else {
                    target.value = null;
                    this.size_error = true;
                    console.log(target.files);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
```

I'm trying to achieve is that when a file input is filled with a file, a `MultipleFileUploaderPart` is created. And when the file input element in this component is filled, another `MultipleFileUploaderPart` is inserted.

I'd like to call `MultipleFileUploader` 's `fileSelected` method from newly inserted components so that I can create another component.

I also want to remove a `MultipleFileUploaderPart` component when the delete button is clicked.

How can I achieve this? or is there a better way?

**EDIT:**
This is what I originally had.
MultipleFileUploader.vue

```js
<template>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <multiple-file-uploader-part
                    v-for="uploader in uploaders"
                    :name="uploadername" :index="uploader.id"
                    @remove="deleteUploader" @fileselected="fileSelected($event)">
                slot
            </multiple-file-uploader-part>
        </div>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    import MultipleFileUploaderPart from "./MultipleFileUploaderPart";

    let index_count = 1;
    export default {
        //name: "MultipleFileUploader",
        components: {MultipleFileUploaderPart},
        props: {
            uploadername: {
                type: String,
                default: 'files',
            }
        },
        data() {
            return {
                uploaders: [
                    {
                        id: index_count++,
                    },
                ]
            }
        },
        methods: {
            fileSelected: function (target) {
                if(target.value){
                    this.uploaders.push({
                        id: index_count++,
                    })
                }

            },
            deleteUploader: function (idToRemove) {
                this.uploaders = this.uploaders.filter(
                    uploaders_id => {
                        return uploaders_id.id !== idToRemove;
                    }
                )
            }
        },
    }
</script>
```

MultipleFileUploaderPart.vue

```js
<template>
    <div class="input-group margin">
        {{index}}
        <input type="file" accept="application/pdf,image/jpeg,image/png"
               v-bind:name="name + '['+index+']'"
               v-on:change="fileSelectedMethod($event.target)">
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button @click="$emit('remove',index)"
                    class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"
                    v-if="index != 1"
                    type="button">
                Delete{{index}}
            </button>
        </div>
        <br>
        <p v-if="size_error" style="color: red">File size must be less than 2MB</p>
    </div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: {
            name: {
                type: String,
            },
            index: {
                type: Number,
            },
        },
        data() {
            return {
                size: '',
                size_error: false,
            }
        },
        methods: {
            checkFileSize: function () {

            },
            fileSelectedMethod: function (target) {
                console.log(target);
                console.log(target.files);
                this.size = target.files[0].size;
                console.log(this.size);
                if (this.size < 2000000) {
                    this.size_error = false;
                    this.$emit('fileselected', target);
                } else {
                    target.value = null;
                    this.size_error = true;
                    console.log(target.files);
                }
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

[And this happens. please click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4RlZ6.gif)

When I click 'Delete'Button, correct child coponent is deleted but the file in the input form stays there. that's why I'm seeking for another approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Declare **uploaders** as an array of objects that contain all needed props for creation of MultipleFileUploaderPart.
2. Use v-for on MultipleFileUploaderPart in the main MultipleFileUploader to reactively generate MultipleFileUploaderPart components
3. Use $emit from MultipleFileUploaderPart to MultipleFileUploader to emit creation and deletion events so that MultipleFileUploader can add or remove elements in the **uploaders** array.
4. Please don't delete or create elements from DOM directly, let the VueJs do this work.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually that what I tried in the first place. this didn't work.the components are added and deleted, but the file inside the file input stays there. I edited the question. please check.

Comment: At least you have to add :key="uploader.id" where v-for="uploader in uploaders" is declared.

Comment: Yes, there is uploader.id passed as :index="uploader.id".It's not ;key but it's ok, right?